# issue with brackets in jQuery Form Data when sending data as json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, object, brackets

I have the object

```
    var dataformdata={"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"};
```

then I add some more values with the same key(key3) like this

```
    dataformdata.key3 = [];
    dataformdata.key3.push("value3");
    dataformdata.key3.push("value4");
```

I do the above in an each slope. It all works except when sending the dataformdata object via the jQuery ajax function in the browser console I see that there are brackets in the key ...

`$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/",
            data: dataformdata,`...

This is what I see in the browser console:

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key3%5B%5D:value3
key3%5B%5D:value4
```

It should work because in the jQuery.ajax() docs it says

> Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting

But why are the brackets (%5B%5D) in the key?

Comment: This implicit and surprising behavior of jquery caused me a lot of trouble when using struts. See more info here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEANUTILS-334

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This notation with the brackets in the key was introduced in jQuery 1.4 to deal with multi-dimensional arrays, or arrays containing objects (or other arrays) themselves. This helps the deserializer to differentiate between an array and a primitive value. For example, if you didn't have the brackets in the key, those two variables would be serialized the same way:

```
var v1 = { "k1":"v1", "k2":"v2", "k3":["v3"] };
```

and

```
var v1 = { "k1":"v1", "k2":"v2", "k3":"v3" };
```

With the bracket notation, they're encoded as

```
k1=v2&k2=v2&k3[]=v3
```

and

```
k1=v2&k2=v2&k3=v3
```

respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. And i found out I can remove the brackets by using jQuery.param( dataformdata, true ), to perform a traditional "shallow" serialization.

Answer (score 20):

you can also use the `traditional` settings in the ajax call
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

> traditional Type: Boolean
>
> Set this to true if you wish to use the
>   traditional style of param serialization.

for example:

```
$.ajax({
 /*usual stuff */
 traditional: true
})
```

Comment: Might not exactly be an answer to the question, but based on above answer, this is what worked for me for sending a mixture of multiple values with the same key, and unique keys and values.

`$.ajax(url, {
  data: {
    id: [value1,value2],
    whatever: true
  },
  traditional: true,
  dataType: "json"
});`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to send multiple pieces of data with the same key name to a script.  You can do this by adding square brackets `[]` to the end of the key name to designate that the data should be interpreted as an array.

The function that does this is [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param).  As an example of how this works:

```
$.param({
    data: ['value3', 'value4']
});
```

`data` is an array.  When it is serialized, it is rendered as `data%5B%5D=value3&data%5B%5D=value4`.  The serverside script will convert this into an array.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly a naming convention — I think from PHP — that indicates that the key (`key3`) is multivalued. It's up to the server to decode these meaningfully.

More details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/