# $.ajax appending [ ] to the key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using Jquery 1.9.1. Having problem in sending ajax data which has array data in one of the key.
This is my code:

```
var obj = {"param1": 1, "param2": 2, "param3": [1, 2]};
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: obj,
    success: function(){}
});
```

But when I checked headers in network panel of developer tool. It is displayed as this:

```
 "param1": 1,
 "param2": 2, 
 **"param3[]"**: [1]
 **"param3[]"**: [2]
```

Why it is adding `[]` to the param3 key? Anyone has any idea?

I have used `$.ajax` before, this the first time it is sending like this.

Comment: That is how arrays are sent as parameters

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(obj),`

Comment: This is normal behaviour, although it sounds like you may need to use the `traditional: true` property on the AJAX request if you do not want it formatted that way. Check the docs for more info

Answer (score 1):

This is completely correct, this is how arrays are send by a request.
It is the same as the html form:

```
<input name="param3[]" value=1>
<input name="param3[]" value=2>
```

`param3[]: [1], param3[]: [2]` is just another notation for the param3 array, in your PHP backend it will be a single variable `$_POST['param3']` with the [1,2] as value. (assuming you use PHP, for other languages it will be an similar but perhaps different variable.)

Comment: While you're correct, you're assuming that the OP is using PHP. This would cause the C# MVC model binder to have a fit.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I assumed PHP, updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The square bracket (i.e. []) added in jquery 1.4 to handle the multiple dimension array. If you want to remove this you should set the  traditional option to true, as shown below:

```
$.ajaxSettings({traditional: true});
```

Following link explain the details. [issue with brackets in jQuery Form Data when sending data as json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011284/problem-with-brackets-in-jquery-form-data-when-sending-data-as-json)